# Reading three specific numbers in a text file and writing them out

Tags: fortran

I have a problem how to print only specific three numbers, which are in a file with no format. I have no idea how to read it and print because if I use read from higher i, it does not start reading e.g. for i = 4, the line 4. I need only numbers 88.98, 65.50, and 30.

```
text

    678 people
    450 girls
    22  old people 
    0 cats
    0 dogs

    4 girls blond
    1 boy blond
    1 old man

    0       88.9814 xo xi
    0       65.508  yo yi
    0       30      zo zi
```

I tried this, but this is not working at all.

```
program souradnice
implicit none
integer :: i, k
character*100 :: yo, zo, line, name, text
real :: xo

open(10,file="text.dat", status='old')
do i=20,20
read(10,fmt='(a)') line
read(unit=line, fmt='(a100)') text
if(name=="xo") then
print *, trim(text)
endif
enddo

close(10)
end program souradnice
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't work out what you mean by "if I use read from higher i, it does not start reading e.g. for i = 4, the line 4" - can you explain a bit more clearly what you are trying?

Comment: At the moment you are only reading one line from the file (because the loop `do i=20,20` only loops over one value of `i`, `i=20`). I recommend adding another `print` statement outside the `if(name=="xo") then` block, to see what's going on.

Comment: What is the rule for determining which numbers to read?  Is it `find a line where the first non-space character is 0 immediately followed by a space, then read the next number on the same line` or is it `read and ignore 12 lines, find the second number on the next line` or what?

Comment: Yes, I want to print only numbers which are behind zero and before xo, yo and zo. Yes, I meand that if I set i = 20,20 it does not read the line 20, but the first line from the file. I never know exactly the position of three lines with xo, yo and zo, so I cannot set exactly to skip the previous lines.

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore the lines except for the three lines where are the numbers I need. But the position of three lines is not always the same and I need from these three lines only the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the whole file line by line, and check each line to see if it's the one you want, e.g. by using the [index](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html) intrinsic. For example,

```
program souradnice
  implicit none
  
  character(100) :: line
  character(5) :: matches(3)
  real :: numbers(3)
  
  character(10) :: dummy
  integer :: i, ierr
  
  ! Substrings to match to find the relevant lines
  matches = ["xo xi", "yo yi", "zo zi"]
  
  open(10,file="text.dat", status='old')
  do
    ! Read a line from the file, and exit the loop if the file end is reached.
    read(10,fmt='(a)',iostat=ierr) line
    if (ierr<0) then
      exit
    endif
    
    do i=1,3
      ! Check if `line` matches any of the i'th line we want.
      if (index(line, matches(i))>0) then
        ! If it matches, read the relevant number into `numbers`.
        read(line,*) dummy, numbers(i)
      endif
    enddo
  enddo
  
  write(*,*) numbers
end program
```

Comment: Where you have written `if (ierr<0) then \n  break \n endif` I think you should have `if (ierr<0) exit` ?